# CakePhp 3 Plugin Authentication adapter was not found

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm kinda a newbie in Cakephp (3.5) and I'm currently trying to make my first plugin (called `Example`) which contains several sub-directories. One of them is the `UserManager` directory which contains a Users MVC standard suit with authentication.

Since I want to add social logins and other stuffs, I created my own auth component as explained in the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects) :

`plugins/Example/UserManager/src/Controller/AppController.php`

```
<?php

namespace Example\UserManager\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController as BaseController;

class AppController extends BaseController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Example/UserManager.Example' => [
                    'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'pass'],
                    'userModel' => 'Users',
                ],
            ], 
        ]);
    }
}
```

`plugins/Example/UserManager/src/Auth/ExampleAuthenticate.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\BaseAuthenticate;
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;
use Cake\Http\Response;  

class ExampleAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
{
    // The same as Form authentication, since I'm testing
}
```

The problem is that I can't make the authentication component find the `ExampleAuthenticate` class. I already tried by setting the `authenticate` config param like

- `Example`
- `ExampleAuthenticate`
- `UserManager.Example`
- `Example/UserManager.Example`
- `Example\UserManager.Example`
- `Example/UserManager.ExampleAuthenticate`
- `Example\UserManager.ExampleAuthenticate`

but I always get the error `Authentication adapter "..." was not found.` when visiting `http://localhost/Project/example/user-manager/users` :(

Does anyone have any clue of what I might be missing?

Comment: I think, there are not support for deep plugins paths. You should use `plugins/Example` or `plugins/UserManager` path

Comment: This is weird, I neither can do it with your suggestion, even though I created a brand new minimalist project just to try this. Is there anything that the docs aren't telling about custom auth implementation?

Comment: By the way, if I change the `authenticate` param to `Form` then everything works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the `php` function `class_exists(...)` didn't recognise the custom authentication class, so after digging a bit more I realised that the namespace shown in the docs only works for a custom authentication file defined in the App environment, but not in the Plugin one (silly me).

So I changed `namespace App\Auth;` to `namespace Example\UserManager\Auth;` inside `ExampleAuthenticate.php` and it worked like a charm! now the function `class_exists('Example\\UserManager\\Auth\\ExampleAuthenticate')` returns `true` and everything works perfect by defining `Example/UserManager.Example` in the `authenticate` config params.